# What does "sit down" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

"Sit down" is to move from a standing  position to a sitting position. However in this context, it seems to have a different sense. Could you explain?

> GOAL - Southampton 0-4 Chelsea
>
> Timo Werner pick the pocket of the defender, **sits down** another and
> hits the post, but Kai Havertz is there to clean up the scraps!

Comment: Looks to have been written by someone with more enthusiasm than talent. They've loosely pulled together some bits of 'pundit idiom' without really quite grasping any of it.

Comment: What does it exactly mean?

Comment: I think it should be: picks the pocket of the defender with an s. It seems to mean get the other guy to stand with his legs bent as if he is about to sit down. This is from rugby but probably means the same thing: https://www.rugbycoachweekly.net/rugby-drills-and-skills/how-to-sit-down-a-defender/

Comment: What is the source of your text?

Comment: I think this is incorrectly transcribed from spoken English. A red flag is lack of an s on pick.

Comment: The OP is too lazy to source it, but it looks like it comes from a live text commentary stream so it's possible it was typed in haste, as quickly as possible to get news of the goal out, explaining typos and cliches.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is unclear as the writer is using metaphors.

It may signify that Timo Werner prompts one defender to spin around away from him, while another falls to the ground (**sits down**) in a failed attempt to stop him. Timo's attempt at goal comes off the post but the ball is netted by Kai Havertz.

The prose is a form of extreme football slang.

Comment: I'd guess sit down has a meaning something like this. Either to put them on their backside on the ground, or possibly to render them spectators to the action (by moving easily past them). You also sometimes talk about sitting someone down and giving them a talking to, so again that might influence it (c.f. one player schooling another). All you can deduce for sure is the defender was well beaten.